# RHEL/CentOS Atomic Host Docker version is old

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

As you know current CentOS Atomic Host Docker version is **1.13.1** ... Do you recommend using this version in production environment? If not, should i update it or find another Docker Linux host?
Note: I plan to build a K8s PaaS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomic is reaching its End Of Life.

RedHat would recommend you to consider using RedHat-CoreOS (base on the former CoreOS). Or in your case, Fedora CoreOS.

Both of which may be used deploying OpenShift. For a vanilla Kubernetes, it might be complicated, little documented, but not impossible in theory.

Meanwhile, note that tools such as KubeSpray would setup proper repositories installing your container runtime.

Comment: I didn't know it is reaching EOL. Ok I will try Fedora CoreOS. It sounds fun.